# How to host a script?

Tags: python, c++, docker, heroku, cloud-hosting

I am trying to finish a personal project, which I describe its operation below.

My project consists of running a script (like a service) in the cloud.

I have on the one hand, a `python` script (created by me) which I want to host, and on the other hand a `c++` script (not created by me), which I need to use from my `python` script, using `boost-python`.

My first way was to host my `python` script in [pythonanywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/), but it doesn't work for me because the `c++` script was designed for windows (it uses libraries only for the `windows` platform such as `windows.h`) and when compiling it ends in an error (`pythonanywhere` uses `linux` as base system).

So I would like someone to help me and tell me what is the correct way to do what I describe. I understand that it can be one of the following variants, but in some cases I am not entirely convinced that it can, or I do not know how to proceed.

- Pay for a [Virtual Desktop](https://geekflare.com/virtual-desktop-hosting-platforms/), and schedule the execution of my `python` script.
- Use what is explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/hosted-apps).
- Use a `docket image` with `windows` and host it somewhere.
- Use `Heroku`

Note. My project needs/use a database.

Comment: C++ isn't a scripting language.

Comment: I use it as a script for boost-python. See an example https://github.com/TNG/boost-python-examples/tree/main/01-HelloWorld

Answer (score -1):

Linux also supports C compilation. It's kernel is coded in C. Try compiling your code on linux with a tool like gcc, available on it.